# The property 'PropertyName' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List<string>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to upload multiple images. So I create a model for storing multiple images. I create a property `public List<string> Photos { get; set; }`then when I do a migration for creating a data table, I get this error:

```
The property 'Shop.Photos' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List<string>' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

here is my model

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ShopingCenter.Models
{
    public class Shop
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "product name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }


        public String Image { get; set; }

        public List<string> Photos { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category")]

        public int? CategoryTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryTypeId")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "SubCategory")]

        public int? SubCategoryTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SubCategoryTypeId")]
        public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I did not understand where the problem. what should I change to upload multiple files? I am a beginner. please help.

Comment: A string is not a photo. What should the strings look like?

Comment: @GertArnold The error is from public List<string> Photos { get; set; } ...a list of names.

Comment: @GertArnold Gert...I see you have a history with EF...and was wondering if you could supply a good tutorial source...I'm having a fit finding any...TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the data annotation [NotMapped] in the model for Shop.Photos.
Its not a primitive type.

```
 [NotMapped]
 public List<string> Photos { get; set; }
```

There is no way EF can convert a list of photos to a database entity.

**To store multiple images to the database.**

You would need a table something like:
Not 100% sure on the data annotations for this.

```
public class ShopImage
{
    [Key]
    ShopImageId {get,set}

    [ForeignKey("Shop")]
    public ShopId { get; set; }
    
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Or instead of actual images in the database...you store the name.

Comment: And what exactly is "working"? Now you have property which does nothing with database - neither can store not load to/from database. Then why it there at all?

Comment: @lvan Stoev you are right.I was checking my data table just now. I can not find my "Photos" property.!! .what's the solution.

Comment: "working" means "migration" and "update" was successful.but I didn't realize the fact of [notmapped].

Comment: @ShaneWatson Was your goal to store a list of images in a database?

Comment: @ChrisCatignani yes. I want to store multiple images and shows.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani as a beginner, I would glad if you give me the proper code relationship between my shop model and your shopimage model.my goal is to upload a multiple-input image and trying to create a model for this.

Comment: @ShaneWatson I will try to help...we can take the rest of the conversation over to a chat room I set up EF'n https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/222344/efn?tab=conversations

Answer (score 0):

// propably this might work

```
public string PhotosString { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public List<string> Photos    
{
  get => PhotoString != null ? PhotosString.Split(',') : null;
  set => PhotosString = string.Join(",", value);
}
```